# Pandas to_csv multiple pages

Tags: python, csv, pandas, beautifulsoup

So as of right now I have FINALLY figured out how to get things into a dataframe but am totally new to programming and think something shouldnt be in this loop hence the problem..

So what I am trying to do is pull baseball data from http://rotoguru1.com/cgi-bin/byday.pl?game=dk

The formatting is correct for the df but I have a few problems.
1.) I have the writing to csv in the for loop for the page scraping which I think I have to take out? Do I just create a new variable to store the information before writing it to csv? 
2.) the paging goes by dates so I just did for i in range(410, 518) to try and get all the dates between april tenth and may 17th.. However obviously it just increments past the 30th day and goes until 99 so I dont see any data for those.

Regardless here's the code I have so far... I am a newbie so take it easy on me :P

```
for i in range(410, 518):
    r = requests.get("http://rotoguru1.com/cgi-bin/byday.pl?date={}&game=dk".format(i))

    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
    table = soup.find_all('tr')[9]
    headers = [th.getText().replace('\xa0', '') for th in table]
    headers.insert(0,'Position')

    data_rows = soup.find_all('tr')[10:430]
    player_data = [[td.getText().replace('\xa0', '') for td in data_rows[i].find_all('td')] for i in range(len(data_rows))]

    df = pd.DataFrame(player_data, columns=headers)
    df.to_csv("testingbaseball.csv")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
import os
path = 'testingbaseball.csv'
if not os.path.exists(path):
    df.to_csv('testingbaseball.csv')
else:
    df.to_csv('testingbaseball.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

This way you'll just keep adding the new data to your csv data file.

Comment: Awesome! I knew it was something simple... And it was really just the mode parameter I wasn't passing 'a' for append im assuming? Thank you so much for this! Now just gotta work on formatting some stuff so I can throw SKlearn on the data :D